# How to use Paging for contact list in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-architecture-components, android-contentresolver, android-paging-library

I am trying to display contacts with search features in a RecyclerView by using the paging library. https://github.com/anujmiddha/paged-list-demo I follow this GitHub project. The following is a code snippet from my project. I am trying to fetch contacts gradually using a pagedList adapter. But this LIMIT and OFFSET is not working as expected in some Android versions such as Android 9.0. Is there any alternative to this?

```
private val PROJECTION = arrayOf(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
        )
    val cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    PROJECTION,
                    null,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME +
                            " ASC LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset)
```

Also, I have tried another way as shown below.

```
val queryArgs = Bundle()
        val cursor: Cursor?
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            queryArgs.putInt(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_OFFSET, offset)
            queryArgs.putInt(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_LIMIT, limit)

            cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    PROJECTION,
                    queryArgs,
                    null)
        } else {
            cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    PROJECTION,
                    null,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME +
                            " ASC LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset)
        }
```

But nothing works for me..